# Maven:calling outside parent pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have basically 3 modules in a project I am working right now

1.ABC_BT

2.ABC_CT

3.ABC_Commons

The 3rd module ABC_Common has submodules common to both 1 and 2.

Now, I am supposed to mavenise all these modules and I am not supposed to restructure these modules.
Now while mavenising,ABC_BT needs ABC_Commons i.e. I need the parent pom of ABC_BT to call the parent pom of ABC_Commons.

I have searched a lot in this topic but there seems to be no solution of calling one parent pom from another parent pom.

Can this be implemented? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What does "calling a parent POM" mean?

Comment: Calling other parent pom from inside another parent pom--this is what I meant

Comment: Yes, you already said that in your question. What does "calling a POM" mean in general (for you)? I ask, because POMs are not _called_. You should edit your question and tell us the steps you are doing and where it fails.

Comment: As I have mentioned, ABC_BT needs access to content in ABC_Commons, so parent pom of ABC_BT needs access to pom.xml of ABC_Common--this is what i meant

Comment: A parent pom is `compiled` as `pom`, not as `jar`. So you can't put classes in it and can't call it... It (if I understand your question correctly) seem you'll need a ABC_parent (pom), in which the three ABC{childs} are in... Then call on jar from the other, using the parent for similar dependencies (incl versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this what you are searching for a is a multi module build which contains the appropriate modules which should look like this:

```
parent
 +-- ABC_BT
 +-- ABC_CT
 +-- ABC_Commons
```

In the parent you create a pom file with the list of modules which can look like [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee).

If you like to use in ABC_BT classes from ABC_Commons you can now simply define a dependency in ABC_BT to ABC_Commons.

Comment: I have started working using this method. Will update you as it goes